# How to make use of attachments and additional columns in modern event webPart new/edit forms?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, office-ui-fabric

I added a multi-lookup field to the standard event list on a modern experience communication site. Unfortunately the standard "New item form" does not show it. My idea is to display the classic newform.aspx in a model dialog inside a modern style webpart. I found out that SP.UI.ModalDialog is not available there and that office ui fabric should be used. I could not find any example which opens a web page inside a dialog, just static HTML. So here my questions:

What would be the best way to show the classic new, edit and view forms in a modal dialog on a modern sharepoint online page?

If it is possible to customize the modern new, edit and view event forms to allow attachments and multilookups that would be better actually, but I have no idea if its possible and how.

Thanks for any suggestions or hints for a maybe better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Events list in the modern page like the picture below?

If so, we cannot open the classic new and edit form from the Events list in the modern page.

In the modern page, the new and edit forms are designed for the modern page.

It is by design.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of that it's by design, but I want to develop a workaround, because the ootb does not meet the requirements. The classic new and edit forms do because they make use of the additional columns and let the user upload attachments to events. I want to provide a button to access the classic newform in a modal dialog on a modern page.

Comment: To answer your question: the event web part was part of the communication site already, I did not add it manually.